# close google map popup on mousemove or mouseout

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, popup

How can I close the popup that opens on hover over marker after mouse move away or out of it?

```
var icon1 = "imageA.png";
var icon2 = "imageB.png";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: icon1,
    title: "some marker"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    popup = new Popup(
          new google.maps.LatLng(-33.866, 151.196),
          document.getElementById('content'));
    popup.setMap(map);
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    // ? close popup
});
```

or rather I need a global solution to close all popups on the map.

the custom popup comes from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup

Comment: i think this `Popup` is a custom function. so please add code of this `Popup` class/function.

Comment: @InusSaha i have taken this custom popup from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/inussaha/otuz1y5h/10/

click on the map, you will see the popup getting removed.

the `Popup` class extends `google.maps.OverlayView`. so you have all the functionality inherited from `google.maps.OverlayView`.

see the following code to add/remove `Popup`

```
popup.setMap(null); //this will remove the popup overlay;

//the following will show the popup overlay. (map must be a valid google map object)
popup.setMap(map);
```

so your code should look like following:

```
var icon1 = "imageA.png";
var icon2 = "imageB.png";
var popup = null;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: icon1,
    title: "some marker"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    popup = new Popup(
          new google.maps.LatLng(-33.866, 151.196),
          document.getElementById('content'));
    popup.setMap(map); // show the popup
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    popup.setMap(null); // close the popup
});
```

Comment: i see your solution, but the idea is close the popup on mousemove or mouseout . the popup gets opened on clicking the marker in the first place.

Comment: check my updated answer, you can use `mouseleave` instead of `click`

Comment: wait, i'll add a close function, which can be called to remove it.

Comment: how can we move the logic of "mouseover on popup to open it" into the prototype? instead of directly in the code?

Comment: check updated answer. and link to jsfiddle. it is much better. as i dont need to define open/close method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173706/discussion-between-bonnard-and-inus-saha).

Comment: I tried to use `google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseout', function(e){` but while it removes it, if we do a `mouseover` then we get an error about the `ClassList`